# Enabling PayPal buttons with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, paypal, payment

Im kinda of a nooobie when it comes to coding, but here it goes, hope someone can help. I was asked to set up a payment page using two paypal buttons. When you first arrive at the page the buttons need to be disabled, until they check the checkbox, that basically means they have accepted the ToS, and there for can continue on to make the payment. I have tried everything I could find online but nothing seems to work for me.

This is my html code...

```
    <!--CheckBox Validation-->

    <input id="one" type="checkbox" /> I have read and agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions


    <!--PayPal Button-->

    <center>
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return confSubmit();"              method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2RU2ND26N2564">
    <input type="image" src="http://graphicasylum.com/images/Boton_100_Chico.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma más segura y rápida de pagar en línea.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    </td>

    <td>
<a class="submit disabled"
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return confSubmit();" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SAK96Y5CBTFUL">
    <input type="image" src="http://graphicasylum.com/images/Boton_50_Chico.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma más segura y rápida de pagar en línea.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></a>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </center>
```

---

And this is my js code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function confSubmit() {
    if(!document.getElementById("accept").checked) {
    alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions in order to continue.");
    return false;
    }
    } // ]]></script>
```

---

If I'm completely lost (witch I'm pretty sure I am) I'm willing to go another direction to make this work!
Thanks in advance for any help. :) Also I had to put my 2 paypal buttons in tables because that was the only way I knew how to set them side by side and centered on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

at a glance...

```
if(!document.getElementById("one").checked) {
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but PayPal buttons are still active wether or not checkbox is checked.